# How to append inside an item of a 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I converted a dictionary in python to a list. Now i want to append 1 to each element of that list. When i print individual elements in the loop, it shows that 1 was appended but when i print the list, it doesn't.

CODE

```
apple = {'a':1,'p':2,'l':1,'e':1}

apple_list = apple.items()

for item in apple_list:

    item = list(item)

    item.append(1)

    print(item)

print(apple_list)
```

OUTPUT

```
['a', 1, 1]
['p', 2, 1]
['l', 1, 1]
['e', 1, 1]

dict_items([('a', 1), ('p', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1)])
```

Comment: Where is 2d list??

Comment: You are appending in item and printing items of dictionary?? How do you suppose that I will update automatically?? You are not changing apple_list it will be what it was before for loop

Comment: Use list comprehension like this: [list(item).append(1) for item in apple.items()]

Comment: @RamanMishra that is *equivalent* to the OP's solution, except it creates an unnecessary list of `None` objects (one of the reasons you **should not use list comprehensions for side effects**) and thus, will *fail for exactly the same reason*.

Comment: Note, `apple_list` is *not a list*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` is a tuple from the sequence generated by `apple.items()`. By assigning `list(item)` to `item`, you're assigning a new list to the variable so it no longer refers to the tuple in the sequence.

You can instead convert the dict items to a list of lists with a list comprehension while concatenating the tuple of key-value pairs with a singleton of `1`:

```
[list(pair + (1,)) for pair in apple.items()]
```

This returns:

```
[['a', 1, 1], ['p', 2, 1], ['l', 1, 1], ['e', 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new and this makes things a lot clearer for me.